# Proper way to sort a multi-object list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have a list class that has a Title (string) Rank (int) and a couple of other string elements. I'd like to be able to sort the list so that I can sort the whole bit by the rank.

For instance:

```
 Title              Rank              Bla1        Bla2
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 Whatever            0                Bla         Blabety Bla
 Something Else      4                Bla2        Double Bla
 Howdy               1                Bla3        asdf
 Last                2                Bla4        fdsa
```

Becomes:

```
 Title              Rank              Bla1        Bla2
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 Something Else      4                Bla2        Double Bla  
 Last                2                Bla4        fdsa      
 Howdy               1                Bla3        asdf
 Whatever            0                Bla         Blabety Bla
```

Here's the class declaration:

```
public class Results
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public string term { get; set; }
    public string studentComment { get; set; }
}
```

And the list declaration:

```
public List<Results> studentList = new List<Results>();
```

**How would I take `studentList` and sort it by rank to get the results shown above?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda Expressions to the rescue!

```
studentList.OrderByDescending(p => p.rank).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the LINQ method OrderBy or OrderByDescending like so:

```
var orderedList = studentList.OrderByDescending(item=>item.rank);
```

**Edit:**

If you wanted a return type of List simply use the .ToList() method:

```
var orderedList = studentList.OrderByDescending(item=>item.rank).ToList();
```

Comment: This is one approach. It should be noted that this is not an in-place sort, and the result is not a list.

Comment: @Greg, depending on how he wants the resultant data, this may or may not be an issue. If so, the ToList() method solves that problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`List<T>.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method:

```
studentList.Sort( (a,b) => b.Rank.CompareTo(a.Rank) );
```

Comparing *b to a* here as opposed to *a to b* will give you a descending order (e.g., rank 4 to rank 0).

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Results> studentList = new List<Results>();
...
studentList.Sort((student1, student2) => student1.Rank.CompareTo(student2.Rank));
```

This does an **in-place sort** of the students. The student are compared using the anonymous function passed to the Sort method (Expressed as a lambda expression).

Answer (score 0):

Have the Results class implement IComparable, then implement the method:

```
public int CompareTo(Results other)
{
    return (other.rank - rank);
}
```

Calling studentList.Sort() will now sort your list correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `Results` class implement the [IComparer interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) and use a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) instead of a List.